# Nautilus: Share image (WhatsApp, Facebook, ...)

Tags: nautilus, sharing, whatsapp

I use nautilus to look at my local files.

How can I send/share an image to WhatsApp or Facebook?

I would like to have the well-known share icon in nautilus:

[image: share-icon]

Comment: What do you mean by the "well-known share icon"? *Well-known* in which context?

Comment: @pomsky please have a look at the question. There is the well-known share icon. In context of digital communication this icon is very wide-spread these days. Please elaborate your question, if you feel like your answer is not answered yet.

Comment: I did have a look at the question, thank you. So, if I'm not mistaken you're looking for feature similar to the one found in smartphones, right? In that case, IMHO you're comparing apples with oranges. The GUI experiences in phones and computers with larger screens are quite different. One can effortlessly deal with multiple application windows on a computer screen. Most, if not all, social/email sites let the user simulataneously upload a bunch of images by simply dragging and dropping to an open tab in a web-browser from Nautilus (and other file managers).

Comment: In any case you probably are not going to get an actual answer to your question here as AFAIK this is not a supported feature of file browsers. Consider posting a feature request to the developers instead.

Answer (score 0):

Open a web browser (such as Firefox)
Sign into the web service (WhatsApp, Facebook, et al.)
Go to where you wish to put the image

In Facebook, click on the camera icon
This will summon your file manager, Nautilus
Navigate through the directories to Pictures or wherever the photo you wish to share is
Click on the picture file and press Enter to upload the photo

I don't use WhatsApp so can't tell you how to use their system, but the process will be very similar

Comment: Why is the easy way which works on mobile devices not available in Ubuntu? With "easy way" I mean the share-icon beside the image.

Comment: That's an answer for another Q&A site, such as https://android.stackexchange.com or https://webapps.stackexchange.com . Every stack exchange site (including this one) has a _Help_ section which explains what that site is for and shows  _What topics can I ask about here?_

Comment: I am using nautilus with ubuntu linux, not android. I want to share an image.

Comment: But you wrote above you wanted a solution _which works on mobile devices not available in Ubuntu?_ Please clarify by clicking [edit] and enhance the question to explain what you really want.

Comment: I updated the question. I just want the well-known share icon in nautilus.